web-push node library delivery timing issue
I am using trying to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/web-push and though I am able to complete the workfloow and get the push message sent to the client and have it displayed on the client using a notification I am having timing issues.
I wanted a message to be displayed at around 17:00 which is the time I am sending it.
I am using a TTL of 60*60 (i.e. 1 hour) with the intension that if the push message was not delivered to the client it will not be delivered at a later time. I am also specifying an urgency of "high" as can both be seen in:
const {statusCode,headers,body}= await webPush.sendNotification(   
   JSON.parse(sub_to_push.subscription),payload,
   {TTL:/*seconds*/60*60,urgency:'high',topic:'TimeToReport'}
);

and even so I got this message at 20:54...
I am guessing I could add more timing information into my payload object and than prevent a message from being displayed at an improper time (or try and adjust it somehow as actually if I get a push message I MUST call self.registration.showNotification or otherwise a default message about the site having been updated in the background is being displayed...
Is there anything I can do about this? How reliable should I expect this service to be?
